# TIBCO Attempt to acknowledge message(s) not valid for this consumer

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, tibco, tibco-ems

I am trying to publish messages through TIBCO EMS. After processing few messages I automatically get this error and processing halts. After some time again I can process the messages around 10K. Here is the error I am getting. PLease advise on this

```
2016-11-30 13:39:31,170 ERROR c.b.e.d.AckMessageListenerController - Listener for Queue[TEST.DEV.QUE] throwed an exception, closing session to avoid possible message loss
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Attempt to acknowledge message(s) not valid for this consumer
```

Comment: Does this scenario signifies if only there are two receivers for the queue in same session?

Comment: In this scenario, do we have stale connections for this queue?

Answer (score 0):

See how many consumers are there for this queue. 
This error says you are trying to acknowledge this message which is not intended for you. 
Does the process started from any checkopint?

Comment: Nope. The messages are produced and consumed by same server. We have this design to communicate between two different application layers. When i checked the queue properties I observed that there are no flowcontrol, expiration properties set. So, will there be a scenario where messages get expire in queue before consumed by Consumer. Will this be valid scenario?

Comment: We are using CLIENT_ACK as ack mode. What will be the good practice when producer pushing messages rapidly and consumer intakes messages very slowly (though definitely it indicates leak in the code at consumer end)